# qt making a window singly-bordered in Windows

Tags: windows, qt

Given a window inherited from QMainWindow, how to make it singly-bordered in Windows?
I have an idea of retrieving its window handle but I don't know how to do it. Anyway, if there is a (combination of) methods native to Qt, it will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
I've tried the code

```
HWND hWnd = (HWND)this->winId(); // the handle
unsigned old_styles = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & (~WS_THICKFRAME) | WS_VISIBLE;
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GCL_STYLE, old_styles);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE   
| SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

and it doesn't work albeit the window handle is a correct one.

Comment: What does "singly-bordered" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a Qt::WA_NativeWindow attribute for each widget you want to have access to or call its QWidget::winId() method which will return you the handle (and create it before doing that).

```
HWND hWidget = (HWND)pWidget->winId();
```

Getting handle, you can change / set any flag to this window, cann't you?
As far as I remember, WS_BORDER flag is the one responsible for it:

```
WS_BORDER 0x00800000L The window has a thin-line border.
```

Comment: winId() was really helpful. Thanks.